# Is there a way to select a group of indexes and remove them?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am making a decode method, which selects a set of index values within strings to remove. But right now the problem is i am unable to understand how to select a set of indices to remove

I have tried making a list of items to designate and remove if found in the string, but this would only work for only a few types of string sets.

```
def decode(string, n):
    for i in range(0,len(string), n): 
        string = string.replace(string[i],'')
        return string
```

here n is the number of values to remove at a given index as well as the index from where to start removing the said values

I understand how to step through an index, but I am not sure how to remove string values according to the index.

```
print(decode('#P#y#t#h#o#n#',1)) #this works out to be Python

print(decode('AxYLet1x3’s T74codaa7e!',3 )) #this does not, this is supposed to be 'Let's Code'
```

Comment: also to add, n defines the group of letters that it will start discarding followed by keeping and alternate until it exhausts the string

Comment: You Need to replace slices not only one char. but be careful the index changes, when you delete characters. I can write a better answer maybe later on

Comment: so that's the thing when I try slices, it tends to remove a whole lot more than whats neccessary, or it doesnt remove whats neccessary,

Comment: So you want 'discard n, keep n' approach? | Btw, list (string) contents move left when you delete an element. Your `Python` example works because it wants to remove every character(! that's how n=1 works right now) and character `P` jumps into first deleted position, therefore keeping it - and so on.

Comment: @h4z3 so would it be viable to replace them with spaces, and then use strip()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *"switcher"* flag:

```
def decode(inp_str, n):
    s = ''
    flag = True
    for i in range(0, len(inp_str), n):
        flag = not flag
        if flag: s += inp_str[i: i + n]
    return s

print(decode('#P#y#t#h#o#n#', 1))            # Python
print(decode('AxYLet1x3’s T74codaa7e!', 3))  # Let’s code!
```

Answer (score 1):

Different approach would be to pick the characters at the right positions:

```py
def decode(string, n):
    res = ''
    for i in range(len(string)//(2*n)+1):
        res += string[2*n*i+n:2*n*i+2*n]
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're returning right after the first iteration. Second, you're only replacing character at n'th position with "".

This should do what you require, it'll replace every 'n' number of characters after every 'n' index:

```
def decode(string, n):
    for i in range(0,len(string)-1,n): 
        string = string[:i] + string[i+n:] # Remove elements at index "i", till "i+n"
    return string
```

Output:

```
print(decode('#P#y#t#h#o#n#',1)) # Output = Python

print(decode('AxYLet1x3’s T74codaa7e!',3 )) # Output = Let's Code
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the size of an iterable when going through it!

The best would be to replace the character with some placeholder that can't be in the string, and then stripping it.

E.g. for your first example you already have that string format. Removing them outside the loop (remember, loop is for marking the characters for deletion) would be:

```
return ''.join(c for c in string if c!='#')
```

As for the loop itself in this approach, I'll leave it up to you to debug it now. ;) See how index moves in the loop, see what your replace in fact does! E.g. as I said in the comment, n=1 would go through literally every character, not every second character!

---

Another solution is smart slicing with indexes. Assuming from your examples that you want to 'remove n, keep n' code:

```
def decode(string, n):
    result = ""
    for i in range(n,len(string), 2*n): # first index we want to keep is n, next is 3n, 5n... so we're jumping by 2n each time
        result += string[i: i+n]
    return result
```